# Python tkinter ListBox height not working

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I'm having issues getting my ListBox to be the proper height in my grid configured Tk. It should be 6 rows high, but it's much less than that.
I'm running python 3.8.
I'm working on a Windows 10 computer, but I don't think that matters.
I think I've just missed something small.
Any help is appreciated.
I've searched and could not find an answer here.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import filedialog

window = Tk()
btn_font = tkFont.Font(family='Ariel', size=20, weight='bold')

# Define functions here
def main_menu_gui():
    pass

main_menu_button = Button(window, text='Main Menu',
                                     command=main_menu_gui, font=btn_font, width=13)
main_menu_button.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=3, sticky=W)
new_question_button = Button(window, text='New Question',
                                     command=main_menu_gui, font=btn_font, width=13)
new_question_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=3)
save_question_button = Button(window, text='Save Question',
                                     command=main_menu_gui, font=btn_font, width=13)
save_question_button.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5, pady=3)
delete_question_button = Button(window, text='Delete Question',
                                     command=main_menu_gui, font=btn_font, width=13)
delete_question_button.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=5, pady=3)
question_label = Label(text='Question', font=btn_font, justify="left")
question_label.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=3)
question_entry = Entry(window, font=btn_font, width=47)
question_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=3)
question_1_label = Label(text=f'Answer 1', font=btn_font, justify="left")
question_1_label.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=3)
question_1_entry = Entry(window, font=btn_font, width=47)
question_1_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=3)
question_2_label = Label(text=f'Answer 2', font=btn_font, justify="left")
question_2_label.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=3)
question_2_entry = Entry(window, font=btn_font, width=47)
question_2_entry.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=3)
question_3_label = Label(text=f'Answer 2', font=btn_font, justify="left")
question_3_label.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5, pady=3)
question_3_entry = Entry(window, font=btn_font, width=47)
question_3_entry.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=3)
question_4_label = Label(text=f'Answer 4', font=btn_font, justify="left")
question_4_label.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5, pady=3)
question_4_entry = Entry(window, font=btn_font, width=47)
question_4_entry.grid(row=5, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=3)
right_label = Label(text='Right Feedback', font=btn_font, justify="left")
right_label.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5, pady=3)
right_entry = Entry(window, font=btn_font, width=47)
right_entry.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=3)
wrong_label = Label(text='Wrong Feedback', font=btn_font, justify="left")
wrong_label.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5, pady=3)
wrong_entry = Entry(window, font=btn_font, width=47)
wrong_entry.grid(row=7, column=1, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=3)
question_list = Listbox(window, height=6)
question_scroll = Scrollbar(question_list, orient=VERTICAL)
question_list.config(yscrollcommand=question_scroll.set)
question_scroll.config(command=question_list.yview)
question_list.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=5, pady=3, sticky=N+E+S+W)
question_list.columnconfigure(0, weight=3)
question_scroll.grid(column=4, sticky=N+S)

window.mainloop()
```

[image: Current Output]

Comment: You should create a [mcve] by removing as much code as you can while still reproducing the problem.  Believe it or not, this problem can be reproduced with only 7 lines of code.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley that makes sense. Should I edit my question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem is this line:

```
question_scroll = Scrollbar(question_list, orient=VERTICAL)
```

Notice that you are putting the scrollbar inside the listbox. When you then call `grid` on the scrollbar, the default behavior of `grid` is to grow or shrink a widget to fit its children, so the listbox is shrinking in height to fit the scrollbar.

Instead of putting the scrollbar in `question_list`, you need to put it in `window`.

```
question_scroll = Scrollbar(window, orient=VERTICAL)
```

You'll then notice that you're putting the scrollbar in the row below the listbox. Instead, you should put it on the same row:

```
question_scroll.grid(row=8, column=4, sticky=N+S)
```

If you want the scrollbar to appear to be inside the listbox, as is fairly common on modern UIs, you can create a separate frame and put both the listbox and the scrollbar inside the frame. If you give the frame a border and then remove the border of the listbox, the scrollbar will appear to be iside the listbox.